# How do I determine time passed between two Calendar Objects in Java?

Tags: java, calendar

What is the best way to count the amount of time between two Calendar dates in java. I am writing a method that determines the number of months that pass between two dates and returns a boolean based on a predefined term of months. This is my code(does not work correctly).

This code always returns false. Also this code does not take into account the number of days passed. This could be a problem if the start date is at the end of a month. Is there not a simple compareTo method?

```
private boolean hasMatured()
{
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    Calendar start = (Calendar) super.dateOpened.clone();

    int nowYear = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int nowMonth = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    int startYear = start.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int startMonth = start.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    int monthsElapsed = (nowYear - startYear) * 12 + (nowMonth - startMonth);

    return monthsElapsed>PERIOD_IN_MONTHS;
}
```

Comment: In future questions, please post as well **what** did not work correctly. What happened with this code? What should have happened instead? Posting it all in flavor of an SSCCE (http://sscce.org) would have been very helpful.

Comment: I see that you've edited the question. What are the actual dates here? Add a `System.out.println()` of `now.getTime()`, `start.getTime()` and `monthsElapsed` to end of method.

Comment: @ZeroDivide:  In one of your comments you say this is for a "CS assignment". Thus, please tag the question as homework.

Comment: @BalusC That is a good idea.... I was starting to think i may have a bug elsewhere in the class that is causing an incorrect date to be stored. I will write a simple test class that test this.

@GreenMatt Thank you for letting me know. I am very new to the StackOverflow and welcome all the tips I can get.

Comment: I found the mistake. I made a forgot to put a call in the toString method for the hasMatured() method. I guess I got in a hurry. I don't know who to give credit to. Everybody had helpful advice. The idea to put the System.out.println(); call in helped me track down my mistake.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int nowYear = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int nowMonth = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);

int startYear = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int startMonth = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);

int monthsElapsed = (nowYear - startYear) * 12 + (nowMonth - startMonth);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would *strongly* recommend [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for all date-related stuff in Java. It has a much cleaner and more intuitive API, togather with the concepts of intervals between dates etc.

Comment: Thank you! I will check this out. However, this code is for a CS assignment and I believe that we are supposed to use the java API.

Comment: Fair enough. Perhaps you'll get extra marks by mentioning that java.util.Calendar isn't really ideal :-)

Comment: Funny how the "correct" CS answer is to ignore the well built and tested free library and to instead become an overnight expert at date math.  Oh, the irony.

Comment: If I use the Joda Time API, would I have to package it with the final build somehow?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to provide the .jar alongside your solution

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine expect from one major caveat: `Calendar` is **mutable**.

So, instead of

```
Calendar start = super.dateOpened;
```

you should have done

```
Calendar start = (Calendar) super.dateOpened.clone();
```

otherwise the changes get reflected in `dataOpened` which may cause unexpected side-effects.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term mutable.However, I understand why it is important to clone the object. I was only passing the reference to the start object, and that is why the changes would be reflected. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something?  There is a compareTo() in Calendar, as well as other useful stuff...

How about:

`Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();`

`now.add(Calendar.MONTH, -PERIOD_IN_MONTHS);`

`return super.dateOpened.before(now);`

Subtract X months from today, and see if the start date is still before that date.  If it is, then X months must have passed.

Comment: The OP did that before, but changed it afterwards to reflect the given answers. Check the edit history (click at link after `edited` in the question).